# Pipeline deployment

Tags: json, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have 2 JSON files:Parameters.json and updatedParam.json

I want to write a yml script that allows me to take both the json files and patch the change done in Parameters.json to updatedParam.json

I am trying to trigger a pipeline whenever a change is made in the Parameters.json file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Shivam, any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to write a yml script that allows me to take both the json
> files and patch the change done in Parameters.json to
> updatedParam.json

DevOps doesn't support this feature, if you need, you need to design your own code.

And if you want your pipeline triggered by a specific file like Parameters.json, your pipeline should be like this:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  paths:
    include:
    - test/Parameters.json

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
```